# Visual Studio append text to end of lines using find/replace with end line regular expression ($)

Tags: regex, visual-studio, find, ssms

I am trying to append some text (e.g. "Fish") to the end of every line in a file using Visual Studio or SQL Server Management Studio using the following settings in the find/replace dialog:

- Find what: $
- Replace with: Fish
- Use Regular expressions: Checked

This mostly does the job, but for a handful of lines it not only appends "Fish" to the end of the line it also puts it at the beginning of the line. I can't discern any pattern to this behaviour it seems to be almost random, with the larger the file the more lines tending to go wrong.

A similar find/replace with ^ (to put text at the beginning of the line) works with no problem.

Anybody know why this is happening? And also, are there any better suggestions for achieving what I want to?

Comment: Why not use `\n`? And replace with `Fish\n`

Comment: @cheesemacfly - that does resolve the issue as well, although it's very slightly off because it won't match the last line of the file if it doesn't end with a newline!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're seeing that, but you might try something like:

```
Find: ^.*$ 
Replace: \0Fish
```

Comment: Well that seems to do the job - I've tried it a few times and no error, but not sure why it was happening in the first place. Were you able to reproduce the behaviour I describe above? I seem to recall this happening on multiple VS versions going back to 6.0 fifteen years ago...

Comment: @metal ["Anchor the match string to the end of a line" is now \r?$](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx)

Comment: In VS 2015, I had to use `$0` instead of `\0` for the first matching group.

Answer (score 21):

This works in Visual Studio 2012 and 2015:

```
Find: \r 
Replace: Fish\r
```

Make sure you tick 'Use Regular Expressions' checkbox:

[image: Replace panel]

Comment: This looked good, but actually not entirely completely ideal, because (a) it does not work on the last line of the file, and (b) the \r actually gets replaced so all the endlines replace the usual \r\n with simply \n. You could get round (b) by using "Fish\r" as the replacement text I guess...

Comment: @cardinalPilot Did you tick 'Use Regular Expressions' checkbox?

Comment: In VS2019's text editor, I successfully used Replace "\r\n" with "NEWTEXT\r\n" (no quotes). Meither "\r" nor "\n" by itself worked for Replace. I think MS text lines end in \r\n.