# Adding text to code blocks in bulk on right side

Tags: ssms, ssms-2012

I know you can use ALT + Mouse Select or ALT+SHIFT+Mouse Select to to insert text along the column of the scrip.
This works well when you are adding something to the left side of the script, where everything is inline. Is there a way to do the same, but on the right side where everything is not inline.

Here is an example screenshot:
I can select the left side with ALT Select

[image]

But I can't do the same on the right side.
Is there a way for to add text where the text ends on each line?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't have SSMS installed on my home computer so I can't check but [this link demonstrates a vertical select](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2016/06/06/sql-server-vertical-select-mode-feature-sql-server-management-studio/) - which is basically what you were doing at the beginning of the row.  If you hold down ALT and use your mouse, you can also select vertically anywhere inside of the row. You will probably need existing whitespace padding the end of the row(s) for this to work

If this isn't what you need - I have always used Excel (or similar), Notepad++ (windows), VIM, or generated select statements to build my queries based on string concatenation and sometimes regex

edit:
[This link StackOverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23399716/11322721) shows how to use regex to add something to the end of the line. By using a regex find and replace, *after selecting the area you want* and make sure it applies only to the select area... You can try something like:

```
Find: \r   
Replace: Fish\r
```

If you want to add a `)` to the end, you might need to escape it by using `\)`

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you can use the command line `cc.aal <yourContent>` of ConyEdit (a cross-editor  plugin) to append text after line.